# Почему на некоторых устройствах файл с сервера скачивается дольше?

Tags: android, сервер

На одних девайсах файл загружается за секунд пять, на других(Samsung J5 - Android 5.1, Genymotion Google Nexus S - Android 4.1.1) около минуты. Из-а чего это может происходить? Интернет нормальный на смартфонах. Код:

```
public static boolean loadFile(Context context, File outFile) {
        int count;
        AppLog.d("loadFile, start = " + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()));

        try {
            CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));

            URL url = new URL(url);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(ServiceClient.TIME_OUT);
            connection.connect();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER_LENGTH];
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();

            AppLog.d("loadFile, finish = " + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()));
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Долгая загрузка происходит непосредственно в строчке:

```
output.write(data, 0, count);
```

Comment: Сделайте логирование, когда заходит в метод, через какое время открывается соединение, через сколько начинается скачивание, когда заканчивается. Чтоб не просто за сколько выполнит узнать, а на каком этапе стопорится.

Comment: @VAndrJ добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все очень банально.

В разных телефонах различная карта памяти (или встроенная память). И скорость может отличаться до десятка раз. Более того, если память телефона "забита" и карта "доживает свои дни", то скорость записи может быть очень медленной. Также некоторые производители экономят и ставят дешевую (и как следствие, медленную) память. Попробуйте потестить скорость записи, например [так](http://www.droidnews.ru/sd-tools-zameryaem-skorost-chiteniyazapisi-sd-karty).

Второе - у разных телефонов разные радиомодули. И как следствие, скорость скачивания различная. К примеру, некоторые WiFi могут плохо работать с определенными версиями роутеров (лично с этим сталкивался). К примеру, Samsung S6 на TP-link скачивал файлы и серфил интернет очень медленно. А рядом лежащий Nexus выжимал по максимуму весь канал. Замена роутера на asus исправила ситуацию. Роутер для передачи может использовать различное кодирование сигнала, а оно может давать различную скорость.

Третье - у разных телефонов по разному размещена антена. Также есть такое понятие как интерференция сигнала. И телефоны, лежащие в полуметре друг от дружки будут жить в различных условиях. [Почитать](https://habrahabr.ru/post/117761/).

Четвертое. На телефоне может быть запущен какой нибудь сервис, например, классический media server, который сканирует файлы. Понятно, что это может сильно понизить скорость скорость записи.

Читая внимательнее вопрос, я заменил слово "Genymotion" - то есть емулятор. Я правильно понимаю, что Вы сравниваете скорость загрузки для реального девайса и эмулятора? Эмулятор конечно хорошо использовать для тестирования кода, но если программа не будет работь на реальном устройстве, то никому она не нужна (кроме мелкой группы извращенцев, которые пользуются эмуляторами не для разработки).